# How to use Zxing in portrait mode?

Tags: android

Currently zxing library supports only on landscape mode.For my app i need to use in portrait mode

Comment: Here's what you can do with zxing 2.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/how-to-show-zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android/16252917#16252917

Comment: As of Zing 2.2.0 there is property you can set for orientation, refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284764/2584794)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just check out issue for Use [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/111) in portrait mode.

Comment: This link is obsolete.

Comment: The link leads to "QR Code doesn't support unicode" issue...
Check this https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/16 instead

Comment: If you are using version 3.x.x, declare orientation in AndroidManifest.xml. For more read https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/README.md#changing-the-orientation

Answer (score 41):

Here is the Solution for Portrait mode Scanning

first declare these two lines in your app level gradle file

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.1@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

*Define a button in your xml file and in Onclick Listener of button write below code in MainActivity java file*

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortrait.class);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

*Write below code in your MainActivity java file after onCreate() method*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(result != null) {
    if(result.getContents() == null) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
        st_scanned_result = result.getContents();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }

}
```

*then create a class with name CaptureActivityPortrait that extends CaptureActivity. The class looks like below*

```
  package soAndSo(Your PackageName);

  import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity;

  public class CaptureActivityPortrait extends CaptureActivity {
  }
```

*And Most Important declare your CaptureActivityPortrait in manifest file like below*

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivityPortrait"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: This should accepted answer. You saved my day. Thank you mate. I switched from Google Vision to this and couldn't find source how to change default landscape orientation to portrait.

Comment: After updating app gradle with: compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1' and deleting the zxing theme in manifest declaration it also worked for me. Thanks allot!

Comment: You sir are a hero.

Comment: Working like a champ, thanks!

Comment: Why does it have to be this way?

Answer (score 25):

I wanted to use the Barcode reader in portrait mode. I found the [solution here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/README.md#changing-the-orientation) 
as mentioned in a comment posted earlier in this thread. I thought of putting this as an answer so it is easier to find the solution for the people having the same problem.

To use the scanner in portrait mode, you need to add the following activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

And that's it.

See the link for more details.

Comment: absolutely one copy and paste fixed my problem... thanks

Comment: Great to know that helped! :)

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: for which version of zxing is this?

Comment: Haha... Glad to hear that! Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Please check as following ([Official Documentation](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#changing-the-orientation))

Add this activity to manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Set integrator OrientationLocked to false

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

`setDisplayOrientation(int)` does not affect the order of byte array passed in `PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame`. **(Refer to JavaDoc for additional info)**

It means that you need to rotate the data return from previewCallback, but this is yuv data, you need to convert to rgb data then rotate them. it is possible to scan barcode in portrait mode but it will take longer because it need more time to process data from yuv to rgb and rotate rgb data.
so the matter here is how can we get yuv data from previewcallback for portrait mode? when we set setPreviewSize for camera parameters it will get exception if previewsize is not supported. Here is the matter of this issue. If the camera driver does not support previewSize for portrait mode (height > width) you cannot get yuv data in portrait mode. And the rest depends on you, you can scan barcode in portrait mode but it take time longer or you have to change orient of screen to landscape to get result faster.

Answer (score 4):

1. In order to make screen work in portrait, set portrait orientation for the activity (e.g. in manifest) and then config the camera: Use camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) in CameraConfigurationManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera). But be aware that:

   - setDisplayOrientation(int) requires Android 2.2
   - setDisplayOrientation(int) does not affect the order of byte array passed in PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame. (Refer to JavaDoc for additional info)
2. Because preview frames are always in "landscape", we need to rotate them. I used clockwise rotation offered by [comment #11](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c11). Do not forget to swap width and height parameters after rotation. DecodeHandler.java, rotate data before buildLuminanceSource in decode(byte[] data, int width, int height)

   ```
   rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
           rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
   }
   int tmp = width; // Here we are swapping, that's the difference to #11
   width = height;
   height = tmp;
   ```
3. I also modified CameraManager.java, getFramingRectInPreview(), as recommended by #c11:

   ```
   rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   ```
4. I did not modify getCameraResolution(). That's the second difference to #c11.

As a result, I've got UPC and other 1D codes scanning work in portrait.

P.S. Also you may adjust the size of FramingRect (that's the rectangle visible on the screen during scanning), and FramingRectInPreview will be adjusted automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Just add these code in the AndroidManifest.xml of your project

```
<activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:replace="android:screenOrientation" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this android library https://github.com/SudarAbisheck/ZXing-Orient

It supports both portrait and landscape orientation.

Comment: Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: @Drew in my view it is decent answer ... the OP wants a version of ZXing that supports portrait more, and this answer delivers exactly that. It helped me with the same requirement.

Comment: I am sure it did. Years ago, resource  requests were fine on this site. The guidelines changed. And when new answers come in with link-only answers, you often get the comments that I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

add this android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" to your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:stateNotNeeded="true"
              android:theme="@style/CaptureTheme"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to AndroidManifest.xml file inside application tag this will definitely work.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Comment: Adding this might cause manifest merge problem. Can you provide a solution that does not cause the manifest merge issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).