# Android Zxing change orientation to portrait

Tags: android, zxing

I'm trying to rotate Zxing display after reading a few questions and posts about the issue.
After following the instructions, the display did rotate, but the rectangle of the scanner
is not positioned as it should (as can be seen on the image attached).

This is what I have done:

1. in CameraConfigurationManager:

   ```
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
   ```
2. in DecodeHandler.java

   ```
   byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
       for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
           for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
        }
   int tmp = width;         
   width = height;
   height = tmp;
   ```
3. in CameraManager.java:

   ```
   rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   ```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Zxing in portrait mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a lot of struggling, I found the problem, and I hope it will help someone in the future.

On `initFromCameraParameters` method in `CameraConfigurationManager` there is an assumption that the scan is `ALWAYS in landscape mode`, and therefor a fix when `width < height`.
If You follow the steps in the question and remove this check, it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented steps 1 and 3 and now I can view in portrait. I cannot find a place to implement 2 and this is preventing me from reading the code in portrait. Where should I put the code from step 2? I cant find a reference to rotatedData anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of zxing are you using?

Comment: I'm using v2.0. I actually found the location for the code in this link. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178

Comment: @conor : Can u please answer to your question

Comment: @MohitSharma I notice you tried to edit question original question. I'd suggest you just leave comment regarding your proposed edit, instead. You can edit for clarity (e.g. clean up indentation/formatting if question is hard to read/understand), but I would not suggest changing the code included in a question.

Comment: @ROb : Okies....... Friends .. second point has been added in decode method with byte[] rotatedData ....

Comment: im using the zxing 2.1 version, i'm exactly have the same problem i tried this http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c46, now it's look same as attached image in this question, where i have to change as you suggest in zxing 2.1, please give some help?

Comment: @Sam - You need to disable the check in CameraConfigurationManager Class which is in com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.
Search for "We're landscape-only" and disable this check.

Comment: now  view finder showing in potrait mode, but it's not decoding any qr code, i'm checking on Samsung GALAXY S III, any thing i missed out? using zxing 2.1

Comment: Prior to disabling the check in CameraConfigurationManager, did the scan work?

Comment: Anyone used that solution in Delphi Xe5 for mobile?

Answer (score 17):

**As of zxing library:2.2.0 support for orientation change is inherent**

Add/edit the following in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
    tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Set additional property at call to scanner :

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

//allows portrait/landscape mode
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);//"additional property"
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Reference link : https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#changing-the-orientation

Comment: this is what I need. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me too. It's worth mentioning that the addition to the manifest should be done even though IntentIntegrator is called from a different Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: which version of zxing is this?

Comment: how to fixed only to Portrait?

Comment: This one worked for me. Thank you brother.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown I realize this is an old thread, and you may have already found the solution. But for posterity, set `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` to `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` although it may give a warning to use `fullSensor`.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for your answer!! it really helped me, one thing that I noticed is that at least on zxing 2.1 you need to pass "rotatedData" to buildLuminanceSource instead of just "data", the line end up like this:

```
PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(rotatedData, width, height);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: Alright on top above the answer I have added yours too :) thanks it works!

Comment: I feel so dumb for not changing this. Thanks, that's a very good addition to the information given in the question and accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

Well I made a small change in ProjectLibrary (xzing project) and able to change orientation landscape to portrait

In `setDesiredCameraParameters method of class CameraConfigurationManager` added

`camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`

.. in my original project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I set `screenOrientation = portrait` and Its working fine on my ICS 4.0.3

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. In `CameraConfigurationManager`:

   ```
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
   ```
2. In `DecodeHandler.java`:

   ```
   byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
    }
   int tmp = width;         
   width = height;
   height = tmp;
   ```
3. In `CameraManager.java`:

   ```
   rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
   rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
   ```
4. In `CameraConfigurationManager`:

   ```
   if    (width > height) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
     int temp = width;
     width = height;
     height = temp;
   }
   ```
5. Change `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for `CaptureActivity` in manifest.

Comment: This has worked for me. It would be nice to get an edit from @Dayanand indicating the methods to make these changes in. The only additional change I needed to make was to comment out the explicit `setRequestedOrientation` at `CaptureActivity#onResume`

Comment: is that editing the source code of zxing library?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a developer of Barcode Scanner. Yes, it takes a lot more than this to make it scan in portrait mode. You have to "rotate" the image data, and account for the orientation of the device, its default orientation, and its sensor's orientation.

[Barcode Scanner+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) scans in portrait mode, and you can integrate with it via Intent in exactly the same way that you [integrate with Barcode Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent). (However it's a for-pay app.)

Comment: It does rotate and scan, the only problem is the location of the rectangle.

Comment: I think you flipped your x and y in the code above. That's how the display is acting at least. x should go with x.

Comment: The flip is intentional as I have seen on an example here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c46

Comment: Something is definitely flipped, as you can see from your image. It's acting like it's in landscape. Are you sure `cameraResolution` and `screenResolution` are what you think?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried various patches, suggested in other answers, but barcode recognition remained unreliable.

I highly recommend using repository below in portrait mode. Try it, it's fast and stable. I used it in my hybrid app.

https://github.com/Dbuggerx/BarcodeScanner

Answer (score 1):

try this : add  `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`

```
<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:stateNotNeeded="true"
              android:theme="@style/CaptureTheme"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your library go to manifest file change the below line under activity tag

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```