# android ZXing 3.1.0 setDisplayOrientation method does not exist

Tags: android, android-camera

i'm using ZXing 3.1.0 and i want to rotate camera library to scan, after reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216943/android-zxing-change-orientation-to-portrait) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797321/not-able-to-convert-zxing-into-portrait-mode-in-android)

I attempted to paste `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` in `setDesiredCameraParameters` method for rotate camera but i get this error

```
Error:(77, 11) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setDisplayOrientation(int)
  location: variable camera of type android.hardware.Camera
```

`setDesiredCameraParameters` method is now:

```
  void setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    if (parameters == null) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Device error: no camera parameters are available. Proceeding without configuration.");
      return;
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    initializeTorch(parameters, prefs);
    String focusMode = findSettableValue(parameters.getSupportedFocusModes(),
                                         Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO,
                                         Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
    if (focusMode != null) {
      parameters.setFocusMode(focusMode);
    }

    parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android), and place `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` before `camera.setParameters(parameters);`

```
void setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
if (parameters == null) {
  Log.w(TAG, "Device error: no camera parameters are available. Proceeding without configuration.");
  return;
}

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

initializeTorch(parameters, prefs);
String focusMode = findSettableValue(parameters.getSupportedFocusModes(),
                                     Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO,
                                     Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
if (focusMode != null) {
  parameters.setFocusMode(focusMode);
}

parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

}