# Android: Camera preview Rotated

Tags: android, android-camera

i am facing a problem in my application, i am using this for the camera preview, but in the camera preview even the person standing vertically  is appearing  to stand horizontally... , it seems i am missing something in my preview

```
mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

plz help me out , thanx

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

I'm not sure if you are saying that the preview is incorrect, or if the preview looks good and the saved picture is wrong. That link above should fix the preview problem.

If the saved JPEG isn't right try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)

I just copied and pasted both hunks of code, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

when you getSupportedPreviewSizes from Camera.Parameters if you see supported previewSize have  height <= width , it means that the camera driver does not support previewSize for portrait mode (height > width). you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode/9510480#9510480) to get more info