# Reverse image on Nexus 5x in portrait

Tags: android, zxing

I've been working on an old project with an outdated Zxing library version that needed to be updated to fix the [reverse image bug on the Nexus 5x](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/484). I managed to update the library but only [portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode) should be supported.

```
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data,
                width, height);
} else {
    byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y
                    * width];
    }
    int tmp = width;
    width = height;
    height = tmp;
    data = rotatedData;
    source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data,
                width, height);
}
```

I'm now facing an issue decoding the barcode on our Nexus 5X device where our EAN-13 barcode seems to be rotated as you can see in the images below.

**Nexus 5X**

[image: Nexus 5X]

**Android 6.0 device**

[image: Android 6.0 device]

Comment: As per the link you posted, seems that many people have the same problem and there is no fix actually : https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/484#issuecomment-168396380
This is not related to the fact that you have change the default scan orientation to Portrait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue, which is [reported on the tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37067958).

> **Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)**
>
> The main camera of the Nexus 5X has an unusual orientation - by Android compatibility requirements the sensor long edge has to align with the long edge of the device, which means the sensor is oriented either landscape or reverse-landscape.  Most Android devices have a landscape-oriented sensor, but the 5X is reverse-landscape.
>
> Since most devices are identical, many apps do not correctly check for the sensor orientation and apply the right adjustments.  If you more or less copy-paste the sample code here:
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)
>
> for the old camera API, it should set the correct orientation for all types of devices (phones and tablets), sensor orientations, and camera facings (front or back).
>
> As you've noted, the JPEG orientation also has to be set, but this has always been a requirement, so fewer apps get this wrong (since phones are often held at random orientations even if the UI is forced-landscape).
>
> The camera2 API is intentionally more user-friendly here - if you use a SurfaceView, the API ensures the preview is correctly oriented.  We can't unfortunately fix the old API to do this for you.

Basically, if you use [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) you shouldn't see that behavior.

Comment: Does Zxing come with a fix or Camera2 API implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as a result you can see that there's no fix and there is no implementation with Camera2 API.

Comment: And it's not planned as per this comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/484#issuecomment-152104190