# How to portrait QR code scanner using Zxing Library?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I'm quite new in Android Studio. How to portrait this simple qr code scanner?

**Library**

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //View Objects
    private Button buttonScan;
    private TextView textViewName, textViewAddress;

    //qr code scanner object
    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //View objects
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);

        //intializing scan object
        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);

        //attaching onclick listener
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Getting the scan results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //if qr contains data
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    //setting values to textviews
                    textViewName.setText(obj.getString("name"));
                    textViewAddress.setText(obj.getString("address"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //if control comes here
                    //that means the encoded format not matches
                    //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
                    //to a toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //initiating the qr code scan
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Scan QR Code" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I already inserted from `AndroidManifest.xml` in `activity` like this

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and `android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"`.

The rest, I can't fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Zxing in portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What problem did you run into when you tried resolving this problem? You say you can't fix it, but can you be more specific? Do you get an error?

Comment: there's no error in my logcat.