# zxing portrait orientation on android with fragment

Tags: android, zxing

I need to make zxing portrait orientation on android with fragment. 
I'm using singl activity, so I don't want to use any activity besides the main. How to make it?

Comment: Could you share some more information about your code? What you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Zxing in portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007194/how-to-use-zxing-in-portrait-mode)